# SQL Server CE 3.5 Select with 2 conditions

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is selecting data with 2 conditions not support by SQL Server CE?

[image]

I am appreciate to any help idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because you don't have DealerPassword column in tblDealer (can't see all the columns). You have DealerNamePassword.